# Visual Studio adds bin file to project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest, coded-ui-tests

Environment:VS 2010.  TFS.

For one of my projects, whenever I compile, VS adds a bin folder to my project.  I can delete it, but when I compile, it is re-added.  This is a behavior I have not seen before and does not exist in other projects in the solution.  Please see picture below for more details.

[image: Bin file is added to the ASI project.]

Comment: did you build it? did you check output directory from project properties?

Comment: Is Project -> Show All Files selected for both projects?  It may just be hidden for Ahi.UITests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That bin file has not been added to your project.  It is created with you build on the file system.  That is why you see it as a transparent file.  If you don't want to see files on the file system, you should toggle this visibility.

You can do this with the third icon under Solution Explorer (in the image you posted).

**Update for Visual Studio 2019**

`Show All Files` is now the 9th button displayed in `Solution Explorer` (it moves about as new versions of the IDE are released).

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it told me exactly what I wanted to know and how to fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's where compiled output goes.

You seem to be showing folders that are not included in your project.  You could just turn off that setting if you don't want to see it.

You could also move where compiled output is written:[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just showing you the directory structure, it isn't really "in the project". Project | Show All files will toggle this.